# Default AsyncTask thread priority (BACKGROUND) is not applied

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-priority

In default async task constructor source we have following code, which sets thread priority to `Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND = 10`

```
  mWorker = new WorkerRunnable<Params, Result>() {
        public Result call() throws Exception {
            mTaskInvoked.set(true);
            Result result = null;
            try {
                Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
                //noinspection unchecked
                result = doInBackground(mParams);
                Binder.flushPendingCommands();
            } catch (Throwable tr) {
                mCancelled.set(true);
                throw tr;
            } finally {
                postResult(result);
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
```

I created a sample application where I created simple asynctask and in doInBackground() I log thread priority via

`Log.d("@@@ AsyncTask", "Thread name = " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Tread priority " + Thread.currentThread().getPriority());`

**Expected result:**
`com.example.myapplication D/@@@ AsyncTask: Thread name = AsyncTask #1Tread priority 10`

**Actual result:**
`com.example.myapplication D/@@@ AsyncTask: Thread name = AsyncTask #1Tread priority 5`

Thread priority of background thread is the same as Main thread priority
`com.example.myapplication D/@@@ MainActivity onCreate: Thread name = mainTread priority 5`

I've tested this on API 19 and API 26. Result is the same.

Why background thread priority is not applied in async task? 
Or my method of reading priority is wrong?

I can upload sources to github, but there not much to upload. Only AsyncTask and log statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that my method of getting thread priority was wrong.

Right approach for getting thread priority is `Process.getThreadPriority(Process.myTid())`

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc for `Process.setThreadPriority`:

> Set the priority of the calling thread

The `AsyncTask.execute()` method executes `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` in a default `Executor`. An `Executor` manages a thread pool and allows you to submit tasks to one of those threads. The class that creates the threads for the `Executor` is the `ThreadFactory`. You need to execute on an `Executor` with a `ThreadFactory` that creates threads with the desired priority.

```
class PriorityThreadFactory(
  namePrefix: String,
  private val threadPriority: Int = Thread.NORM_PRIORITY
) : ThreadFactory {

  private val group: ThreadGroup = System.getSecurityManager()?.threadGroup ?: Thread.currentThread().threadGroup
  private val threadNumber = AtomicInteger(1)
  private val namePrefix: String = "pool-$namePrefix-thread-"

  override fun newThread(r: Runnable): Thread {
    val t = Thread(group, r, namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(), 0)
    if (t.isDaemon) {
      t.isDaemon = false
    }
    if (t.priority != threadPriority) {
      t.priority = threadPriority
    }
    return t
  }
}
```

So when you're executing your AsyncTask, you'll pass the `Executor` that uses the `PriorityThreadFactory`.

```
  val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(PriorityThreadFactory("asynctask", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND)
  asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(executor)
```

Comment: Thanks, but why default executor, when running this code Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND); result = doInBackground(mParams); doesn't change its thread priority?

Or we can't change thread priority once the thread was created? what is the reason,  this code is in AsyncTask constructor in such case?

Comment: AFAIK, the default priority for the background thread group IS `Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND`. The default `AsyncTask` `Executor` is a static singleton, and its threads belong to a thread group that doesn't allow the programmer to change the thread priority. When you create a new `Thread` in the `ThreadFactory`, you're doing so in a thread group in which that's allowed.